# Minimum placeholder Font size for iPad app

Tags: ipad, uitextfield, placeholder

I am making an iPad app and there are textfields with placeholders in it.

There are many textfields, so I don't know if the user will be able to see the placeholders.

Does anyone know what is the minimum font size advisable for a placeholder?  I don't want the user to keep zooming to see what the placeholder says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder's default size itself should be fine. As of modifying the size - it is a string and hence you can't modify the textsize attributes.